# DLookUp to return all occurrences instead of only the first one

Tags: vba, ms-access, dlookup

I check if the date selected by the user matches the tblFestivity of the field Festivity_Date.
If these match I display a Message Box.

The field where the user inserts the date:
[image]

The table tblFestivity and the field Festivity_Date:
[image]

It works for the first record:
[image]

```vb
Private Sub Date_Flow_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
If Date_Flow = DLookup("[Festivity_Date]", "tblFestivity", "[Date_Flow]=Form![Date_Flow]") Then
    MsgBox "è un giorno festivo"
End If 
End Sub
```

This code shows the message box but only for the first record, it doesn't check the other records in the table tblFestivity.

*Date_Flow is the name of the textBox in the first immage.*

How can I check all the occurrences instead of only the first one?

Comment: The `DLookup` returns only the first occurrence when more records meet the criteria. Not sure what the question is.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't posted any question in fact...  My question is: how can I check al the occurrence instrad of only the first one?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want all the results as a list, you will have to open a recordset and loop through it. You can also use the `DCount` that will return a count of all the occurrences.

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is:

I would like that if the user select one date , and if this date is on the table tblFestivity, I need a messagebox, not only for the first record like it is now. Thanks for the answers Kostas K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not finding match because WHERE CONDITION syntax is wrong and not using field name in criteria. Correct syntax for referencing field or control on form is `Forms!formname!fieldORcontrol name`. Criteria should use name of field matching to value on form.

`If Not IsNull(DLookup("[Festivity_Date]", "tblFestivity", "[Festivity_Date] = Forms!formname!Date_Flow")) Then`

Or

`If DCount("*", "tblFestivity", "[Festivity_Date]=Forms!formname!Date_Flow") > 0 Then`

Comment: Thank you June7, my syntax were wrong! It perfectly works now, really appriciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to display a message for each occurrence of the date entered by the user?

If that is the case, then I would suggest you to open recordset with results and iterate through each one and display message.

```
Private Sub Date_Flow_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim dt As Date
dt = Me.Date_Flow
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblFestivity.Festivity_Date FROM tblFestivity WHERE (((tblFestivity.Festivity_Date) =#" & dt & "#));") 'Opens recordset only with dates entered in textbox

With rs
    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            MsgBox ("è un giorno festivo")
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox ("There are no festivities on this day")
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Let me know it that is what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you Milos I've found the solution, thank you for your time, I will also try to adapt yours!